# Let $u = <2, 0>, v = <0, -5>,$ and $w = <-4, 3>$. Find the vector $x$ that satisfies $4u-v+x=10x+w$. In this case, vector $x$ is?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $u = <2, 0>, v = <0, -5>$, and $w = <-4, 3>$. Find the vector $x$ that satisfies $4u-v+x=10x+w$. In this case, vector $x$ is?

My friend tried it and got $(4/3,2/9)$ but im not sure if I understand how she got it or if that even is the right answer?
Wondering if I could get an explanation? The notes my teacher gave me don't help at all!

Answer (score 1):

$4u-v+x=(8,5)+x$.  On the other side, we have $10x+(-4,3)$.  Equating, and solving, we get $9x=(12,2)\implies x=(4/3,2/9)$.

Comment: ah i see thank you so much! so she got the right answer thanks

Comment: Yep.  That she did.